# Declare Module en un monorepo

Tags: nodejs, typescript

tengo un monorepo que en la carpeta packages tiene diferentes proyectos, cada uno con un package.json y un archivo de declaración de tipos index.d.ts. Para el proyecto "a" tengo declarado el módulo node:events con unos tipos y para el "b" con otros, pero es como que en el proyecto "b" se me ponen los tipos del "a" en el módulo node:events cosa que no entiendo y si quito el archivo de declaración del proyecto "a", en el proyecto "a" y "b" se me ponen los tipos del proyecto "b". ¿Alguien sabría cómo solucionarlo?

Si necesitáis algún trozo de código de los archivos de declaración os lo puedo proporcionar.

Comment: VSCode sólo es capaz de procesar un `tsconfig.json` por proyecto, de manera que no puedes hacer que en dos carpetas distintas considere dos ambient modules distintos. El resultado que ves es la superposición de los tipos, puesto que sus declaraciones se mergean